# Checkbox dont stay checked when changing component in Angular 8

Tags: angular

Im trying to get my checkbox list checked even when i leave my component.
The problem is i can even save successfully the selected checkbox but when i leave the component and come back they dont stay checked and i dont know what i am missing

This is my button with checkbox inside.

```
<mat-button-toggle-group class="row"
                         name="payments">
    <mat-button-toggle class="col">
        <button type="button"
                [ngClass]="{'clicked': toggleState}"
                class="payment-button"
                (click)="togglePayments()">
            <mat-icon aria-label="{{'csa.payments-title' | translate}}">payments</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
        </button>

        <div *ngIf="show"
             class="toggle-checkbox">
            <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let payment of payments"
                          class="col"
                          [value]="payment"
                          [checked]="paymentState[payment]"
                          (change)="onPaymentsChange($event, payment)"
                          [class.show]="show">
                {{payment | translate}}
            </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
    </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'
import { ICategory, ICategoryDto } from '@app/api/models/api-models'

@Component({
  selector: 'payments-button',
  templateUrl: 'payments-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payments-button.component.scss'],
})
export class PaymentsButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() payments: ICategory[]
  // @Output() getChecklist: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter()

  show = false
  paymentState: { [key: string]: boolean }

  constructor() {
    this.paymentState = {}
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('payments', this.payments)
    /* if (this.payments) {
      this.payments.forEach((payment: string) => {
        console.log(payment)
      })
    } */
    this.payments.forEach((payment: ICategory) => {
      this.paymentState[payment.name] = false
    })
  }

  togglePayments() {
    this.show = !this.show
  }

  /**
   * When users check/unckeck some payments.
   * @param event click event
   * @param payment payment selected
   */
  onPaymentsChange(event, payment: string) {
    this.paymentState[payment] = !this.paymentState[payment]
    // this.getChecklist.emit(this.paymentState[payment])
  }
}
```

And this is how i call the component

```
<payments-button [payments]="this.categoriesAndCountries.payments"
                                                     (getChecklist)="onChecked($event)">
                                    </payments-button>
```

getChecklist isnt doing anything except returning true or false.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zxvx.jpg
WHen i click on basic data the check get returned to empty
Any help on what im missing?

Answer (score 2):

> but when i leave the component and come back they dont stay checked

This happens because you keep the **payment state** in the **component**, which also means that when your component gets **destroyed**, you **lose** every data that your component had.

One way to solve this is by **storing the state in a service**:

#### paymentState.service.ts

```js
paymentState: { [key: string]: boolean }

this.paymentState = {}

setPaymentItemState (item, value) {
    this.paymentState[item] = value;
}
```

#### payment-button.component.ts

```js
get paymentState () {
    return this.paymentStateService.paymentState;
}

constructor (private paymentStateService: PaymentStateService) { }

/* ... */

onPaymentsChange(event, payment: string) {
    this.paymentStateService.setPaymentItemState(payment, !this.paymentState[payment])    
}

/* ... */
```

Comment: But using a service how to i have the Checked values to the service?
```
                              [checked]="paymentState[payment]"
```

Comment: By using the **setPaymentItemState** method.

Answer (score 0):

See the angular documentation about route state, since you want to save the state of previous route after leave.
https://angular.io/guide/router#router-state

Alternatively you can check this solution:
[Angular 4: Save component state after routing to another component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692426/angular-4-save-component-state-after-routing-to-another-component?rq=1)

A third option would be the **creation of a service that saves the selection state in the database** at each selected option.
To make it more easy to prototype, i recommend you to use [InMemoryDbService](https://medium.com/@coderonfleek/faking-the-backend-in-angular-apps-a10c1b8823c).

Comment: But using a service how to i have the Checked values to the service?
```
                              [checked]="paymentState[payment]"
```